# django1.8.11 migrate installed_apps error

Tags: python, django

I use windows64it, mysql5.6.17, python2.7, mysqldb, django1.8.11 .

When I extracted django-1.8.11.tar.gz, errors-'Can not create symbolic link...'- occurred. I ignored these errors.

I started a new django project and changed the following keys in the DATABASES 'default' item to match my database connection settings:

'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'first',
        'USER': 'yy',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
    }

After that, I run the command: python manage.py migrate

ERROR!

```
    C:\Users\zhijie\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\core\manageme
nt\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\core\manageme
nt\__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\core\manageme
nt\base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\core\manageme
nt\commands\migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations
\executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=f
ake_initial)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations
\executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\b
ase\schema.py", line 91, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\b
ase\schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\u
tils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\u
tils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\utils.py",
 line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\u
tils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\m
ysql\base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in default
errorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1142, "INDEX command denied to user 'yy'@'loc
alhost' for table 'django_session'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database user does not have the neccessary access rights. The error message

```
"INDEX command denied to user 'yy'@'localhost' for table 'django_session'"
```

indicates this.

For development you might want to add full access using this statement

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON first.* TO 'yy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

Comment: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER ON `first`.* TO 'yy'@'localhost'.   Is it not enough?

Comment: At least INDEX is missing :)